# C erro de código

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
    {
           char nome[10];
           float altura;
           float peso;
           char cpf[12];
           char sexo[10];
          }Dados;
void imc(Dados x);
char consulte[12];
void imc(Dados x[1])
{
    int i,c;
    for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
    if (consulte==x.cpf)
    {
        if(x.peso<18.5)
        {
            printf("Baixo do peso.");
        }
        else
            {
                if((x.peso>=18.5) && (x.peso<25))
                {
                    printf("Peso adequado.");
                }
                else{
                    if((x.peso>=25) && (x.peso<30))
                    {
                        printf("Sobrepeso.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x.peso>=30)
                        {
                            printf("Obesidade.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
}
int main ()
{
    int i;
    char verdadeiro[10];
    Dados pessoas[1];
    for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o nome da %i pessoa: ",i);
        scanf("%s", &pessoas.nome);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite a altura da %d pessoa: ",i);
        scanf("%f", &pessoas.altura);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o cpf da %d pessoa: ",i);
        scanf("%s", &pessoas.cpf);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o peso da %d pessoa: ",i);
        scanf("%f", &pessoas.peso);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o sexo da %d pessoa: ",i);
        scanf("%s", &pessoas.sexo);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    do
    {
        printf("Digite o nome do cpf da pessoa que você deseja ver o peso:");
        scanf("%s", &consulte);
        imc(pessoas[1]);
        printf("Você quer continuar? Digite[S/N]");
        scanf("%s", &verdadeiro);
    }
    while (verdadeiro!="N");
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Descrição do problema:**

Ao rodar não consigo acessar o usuário pelo cpf, no código uso **if's** pois quero possibilidades para o `imc`. Não sei o que exatamente tá errado.

Ainda acho que o erro é no `if`, pois quero comparar o (variável) `con` que é o mesmo que o (variável) `consulte` que é onde fica o cpf que o usuário quer consultar ai comparo o `con`,com o `x[i].cpf` para ver se o cpf está certo.

Neste momento em que comparo eu acho que ele não acessa o if e só pergunta se  usuário quer continuar. E não mostra o que quero mostrar o `Imc`.

Comment: Ao rodar não consigo acessar o usuário pelo cpf, no código uso if's pois quero possibilidades para o imc. Não sei o que exatamente tá errado.

Comment: Obrigado por corrigir meu código, eu tava perdido tentando arrumar.

Comment: Ainda acho que o erro é no if, pois quero comparar o con que é o mesmo que (variável)consulte que é onde fica o cpf  que o usuário quer consultar ai comparo o con,com o x[i].cpf para ver se o cpf está certo. Neste momento em que comparo ele não acessa o if e so pergunta se  usuário quer continuar.

Comment: Ok. Vou editar.

Comment: Para comparar strings (array de char) em C você deve utilizar a função strcmp de <string.h> e não o operador ==.

Comment: Declare sua função imc com parâmetro Dados x[] e chame tal função informando o argumento pessoas (imc(pessoas[]);).

Comment: Obrigado, Anonimo. Consegui ajeitar meu código, graças a vocês valeu pela ajuda. Fiquem com Deus.

Comment: @anonimo crie uma resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu primeiro for, de cadastro, você inicializa o i valendo 0 e faz a repetição até que i<=1...Eu entendo que você queira cadastrar duas pessoas(pessoas[0] e pessoas[1]) é isso?

Dai para frente eu nao entendi muito bem o código.

```
printf("Digite o nome do cpf da pessoa que você deseja ver o peso:");
scanf("%s", &consulte);
```

O usuario digita o "nome do cpf da pessoa"...voce atribui isso em uma variavel global e chama uma função "imc" passando a posição 1 de pessoas(pessoas[1]).
Se eu entendi o intuito do algoritmo, acho que voce queria atraves da entrada de dados fazer uma busca no cadastro, é isso?Se for, faça algo assim:

```
 do
 {
        printf("Digite o cpf da pessoa que você deseja ver o peso:");
        scanf("%s", &consulte);
        //percorre o cadastro procurando pela pessoa com cpf = consulta
        for(int i=0; i <=1 && !strcmp(consulte, pessoas.cpf)==0;i++);
        imc(pessoas[i]);

        printf("Você quer continuar? Digite[S/N]");
        scanf("%s", &verdadeiro);
 }while (verdadeiro!="N");
```

Na função imc voce recebe a variavel assim:

```
void imc(Dados x[1])
```

Se voce está tratando de apenas uma pessoa não é necessario criar este vetor. Faça assim:

```
void imc(Dados x)
```

Dentro da função imc há comparações de strings, sempre que se voce manipula-las utilize o `#include<string.h>`, neste caso, comparaçoes, sao realizadas da seguinte forma:

```
if(strcmp(string1, string2)==0) //a string1 é igual a string2? Se for ele executa o if
```

Acredito que isso possa resolver grande parte dos seus problemas.